# Генерация моделей в goadesign с полями-указателями

Tags: golang

Я использую библиотеку для генерации каркаса микросервисов goadesign. Когда я описываю ресурс таким образом

```
var UnitMedia = MediaType("application/json", func() {
    Attributes(func() {
        Attribute("id", Integer, func() {
            Description("Идентификатор")
            Example(12345)
        })
        Attribute("name", String, func() {
            Description("Название")
            Example("набор")
        })
    })

    View("default", func() {
        Attribute("id")
        Attribute("name")
    })
})
```

Я при генерации каркаса goagen bootstrap получаю меди тип

```
type Unit struct {
    // Идентификатор
    ID *int `form:"id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty" xml:"id,omitempty"`
    // Название
    Name *string `form:"name,omitempty" json:"name,omitempty" xml:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

Где поля структуры ВСЕ являются указателями. Хотя в примере, поставляемым фреймворком - нет. Я не нашел какого-то способа указать как генерировать структуры без полей-указателей.

Answer (score 1):

Простите, не внимательно прочитал документацию, нужно при описании медиа типа, указать Required() атрибуты. Указатели генерируются только для optional атрибутов.